# How to make a UIPickerView class instantly report its value for other classes?

Tags: class, uipickerview

I have a UIpickerView "myPicker in MyViewController. The picker is a NSObject in a class called MyPicker.

When I set the pickerView to a chosen value, myPicker does not tell MyViewController its new state instantly.

How can I arrange such an instant communicaton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answere myself.
I used NSNotification.